# How to create custom view in a custom view in Android?

Tags: android, view, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I have created two customs views : one extended from SwipeRefreshLayout (Name: ColorSwipeRefreshLayout) and another extended from RecyclerView (Name:  ColorRecyclerView).

I just want to include the ColorRecyclerView in ColorSwipeRefreshLayout, and finally include the ColorSwipeRefreshLayout in my Fragment.
But everytime I want to call my ColorRecyclerView in my Fragment Class, got a NullPointerException on the object and don't understand why...

There is the code :

ColorRecyclerView.java

```
public class ColorRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
final static int COLUMN_COUNT = 3;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
RVColorAdapter adapter;
List<HueColor> colors;
ApiHelper apiHelper;

public ColorRecyclerView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initializeView(context);
}

public ColorRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initializeView(context);
}

public ColorRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    initializeView(context);
}

public void setHelper(ApiHelper apiHelper) {
    this.apiHelper = apiHelper;
}

public void update(List<HueColor> colors) {
    this.colors = colors;
    adapter = new RVColorAdapter(apiHelper,colors);
    setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void initializeView(Context context) {
    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context,COLUMN_COUNT);
    setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
}
```

colorrecyclerview.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

---

ColorSwipeRefreshLayout.java

```
public class ColorSwipeRefreshLayout extends SwipeRefreshLayout {
ColorRecyclerView colorRecyclerView;

public ColorSwipeRefreshLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initializeView(context);
}

public ColorSwipeRefreshLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initializeView(context);
}

private void initializeView(Context context) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.swiperefreshlayout_color, this, true);
    colorRecyclerView = (ColorRecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.colorRecyclerView);

    setColorSchemeResources(R.color.color_scheme_1_1, R.color.color_scheme_1_2,
            R.color.color_scheme_1_3, R.color.color_scheme_1_4);

}

public ColorRecyclerView getColorRecyclerView() {
    return this.colorRecyclerView;
}
```

colorswiperefreshlayout.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.color.hue.ui.view.ColorRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/colorRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

---

ColorFragment.java

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...code...
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_color, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    mRecyclerView = mSwipeRefreshLayout.getColorRecyclerView();
    mRecyclerView.setHelper(mApiHelper); // Got NullPointerEx here

    // ...code...
    return view;
}
```

colorfragment.xml

```
<com.color.hue.ui.view.ColorSwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/colorSwipeRefreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Thanks :)

---

EDIT : 
I added inflation in initializeView of ColorSwipeRefreshLayout and it works :)

Comment: Inflate `colorswiperefreshlayout.xml` in your Fragment

Comment: That's the solution, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SwipeRefreshLayout should not call  `initializeView` in its constructor.

Since you're inflating it in your fragment from a layout, there are no views added yet by the time the constructor is called. So

```
colorRecyclerView = (ColorRecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.colorRecyclerView);`
```

will not find any recycler view.

An option would be to inflate / create the recyclerview within your `initializeView` method or just look for the reference later on.

A good point for your intitialization would probably be [`onFinishInflate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onFinishInflate()).

Comment: Thanks, it works with inflation in initializeView + overriding onFinishInflate :) But the ColorSwipeRefreshLayout do an infinite loading when onRefresh is triggered, while SwipeRefreshLayout works correctly... Didn't override the method, got an idea ??

Comment: @julian-l sadly there are lots of issues with the loading indicator, many solutions can be found here. Also, could you please accept the answer if it worked? thanks